# Can't change variable value from within a callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, scope

I have the following code:

```
var sLat = "test"; //global var, set outside any function
```

...

```
geocoder.geocode({
    'address': address
}, function (results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        alert(sLat); //SHOWS test, THATS OK
        sLat = "test2"; //TRYING TO CHANGE ITS VALUE
    } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
alert(sLat); // SHOWS test INSTEAD OF test2
```

The problem is that the var is accessible inside the callback function but when I try to change its value, the new value (`"test2"`) isn't saved. Whats the problem?

Comment: When the callback it's called the value of the variable changes. The problem it's that you are alerting the value before it changes (i.e., before the callback it's called).

Answer (score 4):

You actually are changing the variable, but when you do it in a callback, this process is asynchronous, so the last line is excecuted before the code inside the callback is excecuted.

You have to make a promise so it waits for the callback to return before excecuting the rest of the code.

Look at this examples:

[Promise & Deferred Objects in Javascript](http://blog.mediumequalsmessage.com/promise-deferred-objects-in-javascript-pt2-practical-use)